# How to test this failover activemq queue case

Tags: activemq-classic, mule, broker

i got my activemq config file and my mule flows with the "jms:activemq-connector" like this:

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" specification="1.1" brokerURL="failover://(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:61617)?randomize=false" validateConnections="false" maxRedelivery="1" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
```

This is my activemq.xml

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" persistent="false">

        <!--
            For better performances use VM cursor and small memory limit.
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

            Also, if your producer is "hanging", it's probably due to producer flow control.
            For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
        -->
        <destinations>
            <queue physicalName="Example.Queue"/>
        </destinations>

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true">
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
                <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb" useCache="true">
                  <!-- Use VM cursor for better latency
                       For more information, see:

                       http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

                  <pendingQueuePolicy>
                    <vmQueueCursor/>
                  </pendingQueuePolicy>
                  -->
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb" cleanupInterval="30000"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
            If using ActiveMQ embedded - the following limits could safely be used:

        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="20 mb"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>
        -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="64 mb"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61617?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Looks like the failover with those url's "works".

Question, how am i supposed to test the failover??? any suggestions? this is the very first time i implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: nevermind i could solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per requested:

I actually ran 2 different activemq's in separate cmd prompt, configured the conf files inside each activemq folder. That's all.

It worked by doing "failover://(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:61617)" on Mule side.

After shutting down the 61616 one, all the entries would go to the second broker, the 61617 one. so it works great.